# Roland RP401 - GM2 list

Tags: midi, digital-piano

In the manual for my Roland RP401 digital piano it lists sounds for 1 to 41 for **Other** (sounds other than the piano sounds). For the rest it just shows that it is GM2 tones. I have found several lists of GM2 tones, but the numbers don't match. For example Wikipedia has [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI_Level_2). For flute is shows 74. Which doesn't seem to match what my 401 has.

I thought perhaps that 74 may be an offset from 42 where the list starts.. Tried that, and that was not a match either. Found [a list](https://sinclairdesign.com/blog/gm2-sound-list-roland-hp603-hp605-lx7-and-lx17) for Roland pianos, but that one is only for HP603, HP605, LX7 and LX17

Does anyone have any suggestions where to find a list of GM2 codes for the Roland RP401 digital piano?

Comment: There is a MIDI manual at https://static.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/RP401R_F-130R_MI.pdf which shows the codes.

Comment: Those lists don't correspond with my Roland key midi list either! Some have moved, some have been re-named. I thought the general idea of GM was to standardise the sounds/numbers so it was universal. Some may start at 0, others at 1, but this is approaching random!

Comment: Thanks @PeteCon the PDF in that URL seems to match the sounds in my RP401